# Checkbox doesn't apply stylesheets on JavaScript checkbox check

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

What would be the solution for applying the attached stylesheets on the checkbox `::before{}` pseudoelement when it's checked? As soon as I have supplied the `checked={checked}` property, the attached stylesheets shop working

```
export const ThemeSwithcer: FC = () => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {                
        if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
            setTheme('theme-dark');
            setChecked(false);
        } else {
            setTheme('theme-light');
            setChecked(true);
        }
    }, [checked]);

    const setTheme = (themeName: string) => {
        localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
        document.documentElement.className = themeName;
    }

    const themeChangeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
            setTheme('theme-light');
        } else {
            setTheme('theme-dark');
        }
    }

    return (
        <label className="Theme-Switcher">
            <input className="Theme-Switcher-Util" type="checkbox" onChange={themeChangeHandler} checked={checked} />
            <span className="Theme-Switcher-Slider round"></span>
        </label>
    );
}
```

```
&:checked + .Theme-Switcher-Slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(24px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(24px);
  transform: translateX(24px);
  background: white url('https://i.ibb.co/7JfqXxB/sunny.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

- CSS: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-cartwright-mvwei?file=/src/styles.css
- SCSS: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-scss-forked-oprzc?file=/src/styles.scss

Also, you have to delete the:

```
useEffect(() => {                
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
    setTheme('theme-dark');
    setChecked(false);
  } else {
    setTheme('theme-light');
    setChecked(true);
  }
}, [checked]);
```

And can see how it works in this image: https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-f94608df776f.gif

**Explanation**

- With this `useEffect` you're setting back the value of check.

Not clear if you want to apply the styles to the checked element or to the span next to it.

So, I created one codesandbox for both examples, you can check it: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-brook-ktw08?file=/src/styles.css

But the code would be:

In the next code you will see one example for:

1. CSS Selector for normal Checkbox
2. CSS Selector for Checked Checkbox
3. CSS Selector for Checked Checkbox Before
4. CSS Selector for Neighbor Before for Checkbox
5. CSS Selector for Neighbor Before for Checked Checkbox

The rules in the previous 3 are just examples. The rules in the last 2 are to show the moon and sun based on your code and specific needs.

**Important** I'd say your missing part is the `content: ' '; display: inline-block` in the modifications for before elements. Basically, without those 2 attributes, you won't be able to see the before because its default size is 0x0.

```css
/* 1. Checkbox */
.Theme-Switcher-Util {
  margin-right: 36px;
}

/* 2. Checked Element */
.Theme-Switcher-Util:checked {
  margin-right: 36px;
}

/* 3. Before of the Checked Element */
.Theme-Switcher-Util:checked::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
}

/* 4. Before of the Slider after the NOT Checked Element */
.Theme-Switcher-Util + .Theme-Switcher-Slider::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background: white url('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/cc/d4/46/ccd4469667ba2915b82d48e28700843a.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* 5. Before of the Slider after the Checked Element */
.Theme-Switcher-Util:checked + .Theme-Switcher-Slider::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background: white url('https://i.ibb.co/7JfqXxB/sunny.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: What i want is that when the checkbox state is set to checked with JavaScript, the supplied stylesheets would apply to the `before` pseudoelement. Is this generally possible?

Comment: In that case, your needed selector is 3 `.Theme-Switcher-Util:checked::before` for checked before or 5 `.Theme-Switcher-Util:checked + .Theme-Switcher-Slider::before` for the span next to it. Also, include `  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;` or it won't work

Comment: In the codesandbox you can see the moon/sun with the checkbox :)

Comment: You can check this specific sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-cartwright-mvwei?file=/src/styles.css with your specific case and without other examples

Comment: could you please guide me through? =c here is the full scss code snippet https://jsfiddle.net/j1hv8Ly7/

Comment: @SharedUser https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-scss-forked-oprzc?file=/src/styles.scss

Comment: still refuses to work as expected. It does not apply the stylesheets on uncheck =c. Should the `checked={checked}` affect it somehow? :c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236706/discussion-between-joseglego-and-shared-user).

Comment: Also, if you check the code in codesandbox I removed the `useEffect` because it's affecting the check. It's what is happening at your end. You can check the codesandbox working without them.

Comment: You can see a video here: https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-f94608df776f.gif